# Exit application without closing all the files

Tags: excel

I am trying to provide an option to my users to save and close excel application after they finish to complete a specific form.  However, it is closing the whole Excel and not only the current Excel workbook that they just used. In other words, if they have 4 different Excel files opened, it will close all of them and not only the current workbook. What am I doing wrong?
This is the code that I am using:

```
ThisWorkbook.Application.Quit
    ThisWorkbook.Save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not quit the Application - but close the workbook:

`ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True`

will save and close the workbook.

If it is the only open workbook, Excel gets closed as well.
If not Excel and the other workbooks are still open.